# Font zooming without a wheel

Tags: windows-7, mouse-wheel

Ever since Windows 7 I've found my desktop's mouse has the magical ability to zoom the font used within most apps if I hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> while rotating the mouse wheel.

Is there a way I can implement this magic on a laptop that using a pressure pad instead of a mouse?

Comment: Did you check the mouse settings in the control panel? Interestingly, a Google search shows more people wanting to **disable** this feature than the opposite.

Comment: :awaits a correlation twixt searcher's ages and that Boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Ctrl + '+' and Ctrl + '-'.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl + wheel to scroll has worked for about ten years or more in many apps including MS Office and several browsers (certainly IE and Firefox, I think). Certainly on XP, possibly older Windows versions too (although wheel mice were much more a speciality item back then).

Office 2007 and 2010 suite has a zoom bar in the bottom right corner that you can use to zoom if you have no wheel - slide the slider or click the +/- buttons.

IE and Firefox both use Ctrl+ and Ctrl- to zoom in (larger) and out, and Ctrl-0 (zero) to reset. In fact, they also use Ctrl= (which is the key where + is written too, but strictly this would be Ctrl-Shift-= to get Ctrl+).

Opera does not recognise Ctrl= nor Ctrl-Shift-=, you can only use Ctrl-[numeric keypad]+. Ctrl- and Ctrl-0 are fine though.

Most recent trackpads have a scroll zone on the right and sometimes also the bottom of the pad, often marked with a series of short parallel lines. Sliding your finger in this zone will be interpreted as a scroll, if you configure this correclty (usually the default but if you have rebuilt a laptop from a plain vanilla Windows 7 install you may not have manufacturer-specific drivers or utilities unless you install them)

Answer (score 0):

I you have a Synaptics touchpad on your laptop, you can enable multitouch gestures, where you can pinch two fingers to zoom in, like on an iPhone, [**by using this modified driver**](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/05/31/enable-multi-touch-gesture-finger-scroll-momentum-and-chiralmotion-on-synaptics-touchpad-in-windows-7vistaxpserver/).

I think the reason that it is normally disabled must be because Apple own the patent on this, and Synaptics have not licenced its use.

I've not used it myself, as I use ThinkPad X-series ultracompact notebooks, which have no trackpad.